# Maximum value of row id?

Tags: android, sqlite

i am developing a android database application in which i use a query to find the maximum of row id in the table which is primary key and not auto incremented 
i referred this link 
http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html

and fired the query

SELECT MAX(gameId) FROM configureGame;

and it returns the maximum value 9 all the time though maximum id in the table is 10

what should i do to get the right value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is data type of gameId?
if it is int then max(gameId) will  return right value.
But if it is String  then it will return wrong value.

Comment: Thanks @Unicusand my game id data type was text

Answer (score 1):

Try using

[`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ROWID();`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html)

Comment: is my query right                                       SELECT last_insert_rowid() FROM configureGame;